# Heroku - how to reconnect Mailgun to my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, mailgun, ruby-on-rails-6.1

Im working on a project with Ruby on Rails language, deployed to Heroku everything is working fine
I had Mailgun addon installed in my Heroku app
at one point I tried to change it to another mailing Addon
so I unlinked the Mailgun addon and connected another Addon
after a little research, I wanted to connect back the Mailgun addon.

when I tried to connect Mailgun again, it said that my app has an account and I cant reconnect it
I cant access my account by the email written in the Heroku's error notification.

what should I do at this point?

In that link below, there is an image of the error I get in my terminal.

[Heroku Error for command: " heroku addons:create mailgun:starter"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN1n7.png)

Another link for an image of the error I get when trying to add Mailgun addon through my heroku app dashboard.
[Heroku Error from Heroku dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQEq0.png)

If you think I should use another mailer addon, I would love to hear about it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what is happening? For example, what is the exact error message? Without specific details, it would be hard to understand precisely your situation and thus harder to give an answer.

Comment: @MasaSakano Hey, did u check the image I added in the "Link" thingy ?

Comment: Please include the image in the question itself. The external link does not count according to the Stackoverflow guideline (I recommend you to read through the guideline – it is fairly strict!). Also, please state what you did in your word, too, (I mean what caused the error output) – that's another point of the guideline.

Comment: Hey @MasaSakano I'm not allowed to embed pictures in my questions yet, when I try to add the image, it converts it automatically into a link.